# Collaborative programming in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, agile, collaboration, pair-programming

In Google Docs more than one person can be editing a file in real time. I tried this and found that the response time was a little slow. I would like to do the same thing in Eclipse. Is it possible? If not, then what are some good alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried a desktop sharing tool [like](http://www.tightvnc.com/) [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)?

Comment: I've done VNC before and it's complicated. I'd like to use something that doesn't require me to setup a direct connection to the other person. I'd prefer to use something that already uses a connection known to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saros is what you are looking for

http://www.saros-project.org/

Saros - Eclipse Distributed Collaborative Editing and Distributed Party Programming

Answer (score -3):

You could try some form of [Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). Programmers don't normally edit the same copy of a document for various practical reasons.

Eclipse has an excellent [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) plug-in called [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Comment: This question is about pair-programming where two developers collaborate on the same code at the same time.

Comment: Agree with Paul - this is not about sharing a repo, it's about pair programming.